# Settings of php.ini seem to be overwritten using xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-extension, mbstring

I want to load some extensions, but my changes in the php.ini file do not have any effect. I have xampp installed on Windows and set `extension_dir` in php.ini to `"C:\xampp\php\ext"`, which is where xampp installed my extensions. But when I call `phpinfo()`, `extension_dir` is shown as `C:\php\ext` which is not correct.
Already verified that it's the correct php.ini and did some stop and start of apache.
Also, I checked the loaded modules with `get_loaded_extensions()`, but my desired extension -mbstring etc- aren't displayed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: run `php -i` in a terminal and take a look at the beginning section which reads "Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /path/to/php/version" and "Loaded Configuration File => /path/to/php/version/php.ini"
Are they correct?

Comment: 1) Configuration file (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
2) Loaded Configuration File => C:\xampp\php.ini

so to me it seems 1) is not correct? There is no php.ini file in C:\Windows

Comment: And what about `Loaded Configuration File`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was an unexpected sign `&` somewhere else in the php.ini file. Found it by typing prompt `php`.